# Graphql with Azure functions

Tags: azure, graphql, azure-functions

is there a way to implement Graphql  via azure functions and nodejs. For example, something like - https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-server-lambda

Comment: Even though this feature doesn't exists built-in on azure functions, but do you're able to use some libs that there are for .NET, as an example:

https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet

Answer (score 7):

Apollo provides Azure Function Integration for GraphQL:

[apollo-server-azure-functions](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/apollo-server-azure-functions)

Here is the sample provided on their github repo:

```
const server = require("apollo-server-azure-functions");
const graphqlTools = require("graphql-tools");

const typeDefs = `
  type Random {
    id: Int!
    rand: String
  }

  type Query {
    rands: [Random]
    rand(id: Int!): Random
  }
`;

const rands = [{ id: 1, rand: "random" }, { id: 2, rand: "modnar" }];

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    rands: () => rands,
    rand: (_, { id }) => rands.find(rand => rand.id === id)
  }
};

const schema = graphqlTools.makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

module.exports = function run(context, request) {
  if (request.method === "POST") {
    server.graphqlAzureFunctions({
        endpointURL: '/api/graphql'
    })(context, request);
  } else if (request.method === "GET") {
    return server.graphiqlAzureFunctions({
        endpointURL: '/api/graphql'
    })(context, request);
  }
};
```

Comment: I found this recently on the Apollo website. I created an Azure Function, pasted the code in, but have no idea how to actually get it to work. There is _nothing_ in the docs that explains how to actually make it work. If there is a blog post out there that shows how to set it up, I'd love to read it!

Comment: I guess just create an azure function and paste the code in the editor

Comment: Just pasting the code into an Azure Function doesn't work, I'm afraid. I'm missing something.

Comment: Did you add the npm packages in the packages.config file ?

Answer (score 4):

So I got this working using Apollo and Azure Functions. There is a mistake in the example for `apollo-server-azure-functions`, and a minor error in that wrapper library that returns string and not JSON data. You also need to install `graphql-tools` separately.

In the example code the schema object is created, but not added to the parameters passed to Apollo server. The working code is below. I've just added schema to the options passed.

```
const server = require("apollo-server-azure-functions");
const graphqlTools = require("graphql-tools");

const typeDefs = `
  type Random {
    id: Int!
    rand: String
  }

  type Query {
    rands: [Random]
    rand(id: Int!): Random
  }
`;

const rands = [{ id: 1, rand: "random" }, { id: 2, rand: "modnar" }];

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    rands: () => rands,
    rand: (_, { id }) => rands.find(rand => rand.id === id)
  }
};

const schema = graphqlTools.makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

module.exports = function run(context, req) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    server.graphqlAzureFunctions({
      endpointURL: '/api/graphql',
      schema: schema
    })(context, req);
  } else if (req.method === 'GET') {
    return server.graphiqlAzureFunctions({
      endpointURL: '/api/graphql',
      schema: schema
    })(context, req);
  }
};
```

Just doing this change you will start to get data back from your endpoint, but unfortunately it will not be of type `application/json`. For that a small change needs to be made to `apollo-server-azure-functions` to convert the body from string to JSON. I've submitted a PR for this to happen, but not sure when they will get to it.

If you're not patient, you can create your own wrapper function with the code below which will work with the example above and return JSON not a string.

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var apollo_server_core_1 = require("apollo-server-core");
var GraphiQL = require("apollo-server-module-graphiql");
function graphqlAzureFunctions(options) {
    if (!options) {
        throw new Error('Apollo Server requires options.');
    }
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        throw new Error("Apollo Server expects exactly one argument, got " + arguments.length);
    }
    return function (httpContext, request) {
        var queryRequest = {
            method: request.method,
            options: options,
            query: request.method === 'POST' ? request.body : request.query,
        };
        if (queryRequest.query && typeof queryRequest.query === 'string') {
            queryRequest.query = JSON.parse(queryRequest.query);
        }
        return apollo_server_core_1.runHttpQuery([httpContext, request], queryRequest)
            .then(function (gqlResponse) {
            var result = {
                status: 200,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.parse(gqlResponse),
            };
            httpContext.res = result;
            httpContext.done(null, result);
        })
            .catch(function (error) {
            var result = {
                status: error.statusCode,
                headers: error.headers,
                body: error.message,
            };
            httpContext.res = result;
            httpContext.done(null, result);
        });
    };
}
exports.graphqlAzureFunctions = graphqlAzureFunctions;
function graphiqlAzureFunctions(options) {
    return function (httpContext, request) {
        var query = request.query;
        GraphiQL.resolveGraphiQLString(query, options, httpContext, request).then(function (graphiqlString) {
            httpContext.res = {
                status: 200,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                },
                body: graphiqlString,
            };
            httpContext.done(null, httpContext.res);
        }, function (error) {
            httpContext.res = {
                status: 500,
                body: error.message,
            };
            httpContext.done(null, httpContext.res);
        });
    };
}
exports.graphiqlAzureFunctions = graphiqlAzureFunctions;
```

For this to work you will need to install `apollo-server-core` and `apollo-server-module-grapiql` as dependencies via npm.

Comment: Do you have a sample project you could share? Or a good tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

There's no native support for this, but there's nothing preventing you from creating a GraphQL schema that calls into Azure Functions.

However, there are some community offerings in the space like scaphold which work to integrate Azure Functions / serverless providers with GraphQL:

https://docs.scaphold.io/custom-logic/

Comment: The link is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to develop a GraphQL API with Typescript and Azure Functions, here's a starter repo you may consider: [azure-function-graphql-typescript-starter](https://github.com/maximivanov/azure-function-graphql-typescript-starter) (*disclaimer: I'm the author*)

It's built on top of:

- [Apollo Server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/deployment/azure-functions/)
  with Azure Functions integration
- [TypeGraphQL](https://typegraphql.com/) to make developing GraphQL APIs simple
  and fun
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) as persistence layer
- [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/#/) for database migrations and useful repository
  classes