# Getting data from API inside a graphQL resolver deployed on Azure node.js function

Tags: azure, graphql, azure-functions, graphql-js

I am trying to deploy a GraphQL server on node.js platform using Azure functions. I have been able to deploy a basic `hello world` app.
However, I need to get data from a backend API in the resolver. I am not able to get either `fetch` or `request` package to work in Azure functions.
Below is my code:

```
var { graphql, buildSchema } = require('graphql');  
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
var request = require('request');

var schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    myObject: MyObject
  }

  type MyObject { 
   someId (data: String) : String
  }
`);

var root = { 
  myObject: () => {
     return { 
        someId: (args) => {
            // Code enters till this point. 
            // I can see context.info messages from here. 
            // return "hello";  <--- This works perfectly fine. 
            return request('http://example.com', function (error, response, body) {
                    // -----> Code never enters here.
                    return body;
                });                   
          }
       }   
   }
};

module.exports = function (context, req) {
     context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
     graphql(schema, req.body, root)
        .then(response => {
           context.res = {
               body: JSON.strigify(response)
          };

    context.done();
 });
};
```

I have tried using `fetch` and `request` modules. But with both of them, I see the same behavior - the response never returns. The request eventually times out after 5 minutes. If instead of `fetch` or `request`, I choose to return some dummy value, I see the response getting returned correctly to the query. With `fetch`, I don't see the `then` block or the `catch` block ever executing.

Note: I have tried both `http` and `https` URLs in the request URIs but none of them seem to return any data.

Is it an issue with the way I have implemented the `fetch`/`request` or is it an issue with Azure functions in general?

Comment: Have you check this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123969/graphql-with-azure-functions/46534235#46534235

Comment: ^ 1. This is all static data which works fine. I need to fetch data from the API.
2. This uses Apollo-graphQL. I am using vanilla graphQL

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: 
It seems that node-fetch and request don't actually return promises. Wrapping the `request` around Promise seems to solve the problem. Something similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929944/how-do-i-call-an-asynchronous-node-js-function-from-within-a-graphql-resolver-re/43930327#43930327).